# C++ Constructor Oder

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor

Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class cls
{
public:
        cls(int i=0) {cout<<" c1 ";}
        ~cls() {cout<<" d 1 ";}
};
class cls2
{
 cls xx;
public:
        cls1(int i=0){cout<<" c2 ";}
        ~cls1(){cout<<" d2 ";}
}c;
class cls3
{
    cls2 xx; cls xxx;
public:
    cls2(int i=0) {cout<<" c3 ";}
    ~cls2(){ cout<<" d3 ";}
};
int main()
{
    cls3 s;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, when I run it, it outputs:

> c1 c2 c1 c2 c1 c3 d3 d1 d2 d1 d2 d1

and I can't seem to figure out why, in my head, it should output:

> c1 c2 c1 c3 d3 d1 d2 d1

because:

```
cls2 s -> cls1 xx -> cls xx => c1
                           => c2
                -> cls xxx => c1
                => c3
```

I know that somewhere, my logic is flawed, but I don't know where.

Comment: Please use consistent names and values! cls1 should print c1 and d1.

Comment: not sure about your logic, but your naming convention is flawed. I find it confusing that `cls2` prints `c3` while `cls1` prints `c2`.

Comment: Could you make the presentation a little less obtuse and baffling?

Comment: Do the `x` members or the constructor parameters have any relevance?

Comment: @tobi303,  I edited it a little bit, hope it's better now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are creating an extra global instance `c` here:

```
class cls1
{
    int x; cls xx;
public:
        cls1(int i=0){cout<<" c2 ";x=i;}
        ~cls1(){cout<<" d2 ";}
} c; // <-- here
```

That one is created first.

Otherwise your expected order is spot-on.

Comment: Right, I failed to notice that c, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: And BTW, declaring variables this way is highly obscure in C++.  I dont think I've ever seen any production / professional code written declaring variables this way (after the class definition).